# Yii2 Gridview Filter not working?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have tried too many ways for this but doesn't find any solution.

GridView:

```
       [
        'attribute' => 'lbt_book_master_id',
        'value' => function($model){
            return LibraryBorrowTransaction::getBookName($model->lbt_book_master_id); },
        'filter' => LibraryBorrowTransaction::getBN(),
        ],
```

Method:

```
public function getBN()
{

    $books_data = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(["lbd_title as value","lbd_id as id"])
        ->from('lib_book_master lbm')
        ->join('join','lib_book_details lbs','lbm.lbm_book_details_id = lbd_id')
        ->join('join', 'lib_borrow_transaction lbt', 'lbm.lbm_book_no = lbt_book_master_id')
        ->where('lbm.lbm_book_no = lbt.lbt_book_master_id')
        ->groupBy('lbd_id')
        ->all();

    $data = ArrayHelper::map($books_data, 'id', 'value');
    return $data;
}
```

Why filter is not working?

Comment: do you set this filter for *book_details_id* attribute ?

Comment: no, filter working on book_title of book_details tables

Comment: showing book_details index.php  as book_master index.php